# ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property title not found on flash.text.TextField and there is no default value

Tags: actionscript-3

I get the following output when clicking "libraryButton". I have looked through other answers to similar questions but can;t find one that helps.

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property title not found on flash.text.TextField and there is no default value.
at HarmonyMusic_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at HarmonyMusic_fla::MainTimeline/openLibrary()
```

This is my code on the "Home" frame

```
//When program starts, open the home page

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

gotoAndStop("Home");

//Make "conservatoriumButton" listen for a mouse click and call the "openConservatorium" function
conservatoriumButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openConservatorium);

function openConservatorium(event:MouseEvent):void{
//Open webpage "http://www.griffith.edu.au/music/queensland-conservatorium" when function is called
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.griffith.edu.au/music/queensland-conservatorium"), "_blank");  
}
griffithButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openGriffith);

function openGriffith(event:MouseEvent):void{
//Open webpage "http://www.griffith.edu.au" when function is called
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.griffith.edu.au"), "_blank");  
}
//Make "libraryButton" listen for a mouse click and call the "openLibrary" function
libraryButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openLibrary);

function openLibrary(event:MouseEvent):void{
//Goto the frame named "MusicLibrary"
gotoAndStop("MusicLibrary");
}
searchButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, searchGoogle);
//searchBar.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.ENTER, searchGoogle);

function searchGoogle(event:MouseEvent):void{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com.au/search?q="+searchBar.text), "_blank");
}
```

EDIT: I turned on debug mode and this is what came up:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property title not found on flash.text.TextField and there is no default value.
at HarmonyMusic_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()[HarmonyMusic_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:80]
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at HarmonyMusic_fla::MainTimeline/openLibrary()[HarmonyMusic_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:24]
```

The code on frame 2 line 80:

```
function chooseSong(e:MouseEvent):void{
/*line 80*/switch(e.currentTarget.name){
    case "song1":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[0] as String;
        quartetsAlbum.visible=true;
        butterflyAlbum.visible=false;
        tapTouchAlbum.visible=false;
        lookingAlbum.visible=false;
        break;
```

and this is the code for frame 1 line 24

```
function openLibrary(event:MouseEvent):void{
/*line 24*/gotoAndStop("MusicLibrary");
}
```

buttons calling chooseSong

```
song1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song11.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song12.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
```

Comment: No other code is being called. I don't understand what you mean by a component.

Comment: I imported a picture to stage and changed the instance name. There is more code on frame 2.

Comment: Frame2 is where the error is. Post that code instead.
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property title not found on flash.text.TextField and there is no default value.
at HarmonyMusic_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()

Comment: I edited the post with the new code.

Comment: Can you post the code which adds the listener which calls "chooseSong"? At this point I am guessing that you didn't disable the mouse or didn't turn off mouseChildren on the main movieclip, so the target is not the target you think it is.

Comment: There are 12 buttons ill edit the post againn

Comment: Instead of a switch statement, try making 12 functions instead. Then see if you still have the error. Something else looks wrong though, but it might avoid the situation that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a search in the code for `title` and post the lines containing it. My best guess is that you have a dynamic `TextField` and you are trying to write the name of the song there. Something along the lines of:

```
    myText.title = "Wrong!"; // is wrong; there is no such property
    myText.text = "Right!"; // the correct way to set the text in a textfield
```

But this is just a wild guess.